# How can a conductor have voltage without charge on it? Taking in electrostatics

Tags: charge, electrostatic, conductors

What does it mean if the potential of a conductor is Kq/r which is at r distance from the charge q? How can a conductor having no real charge have some potential (which is here KQ/r)?

Comment: It took me seconds to find [this youtube](https://youtu.be/G7NSlEmcyog) which may help out. It's applicable, though the exact details are slightly different.

Comment: According to the video you suggested, we can say that the conductor can have some potential even it doesn't have any real charges on it? Am I right?

Comment: This can help: http://www.falstad.com/emstatic/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it;'s about physics, not electrical circuits. Please ask in a physics stack exchange.

Comment: NB: If a "conductor" is placed in the presence of the electric field "induced" by an initial charge, there will be a "change in the field" such that the initial value will no longer be valid. There will be an "induced" charge which will fundamentally modify the initial field. So we end up with a "particular" capacitor.

Comment: See this, for example https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdspn.png https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/18-7-conductors-and-electric-fields-in-static-equilibrium/

Answer (score 2):

If there are "no real charges" then Q = 0 and there is no potential.

Comment: I want to correct you that the potential of a conductor at r distance from the point charge q is equal to Kq/r

Comment: My point is that the potential is 0 if Q = 0.

Comment: Is really a "potential" defined "absolutely" ?

Comment: k= 1/(4*pi*Epsilon0)   ... epsilon0 is permittivity of "vaacum"

Comment: This formula is valid when there is NO conductor! So, it is "unmeasurable".

Comment: I don't know what @Antonio51 mean by "Is really a "potential" defined "absolutely" ? "But this potential is the very reason for the charging by electrostatic induction. So this potential plays a role and it's measurable too.

Comment: The notion of "potential" is linked to the integration of the electric field "E". Like any integral, there is the appearance of a term which is obtained by "boundary conditions", which are not present in this case (or then at infinity). Only the notion of "potential difference" or "voltage" is "exact".

Answer (score 0):

The notion of "potential" is linked to the integration of the electric field "E". Like any integral, there is the appearance of a term which is obtained by "boundary conditions", which are not present in this case (or then at infinity). Only the notion of "potential difference" or "voltage" is "exact".

If a "conductor" is placed in the presence of the electric field "induced" by an initial charge, there will be a "change in the field" such that the initial value will no longer be valid. There will be an "induced" charge which will fundamentally modify the initial field. So we end up with a "particular" capacitor.

from this document, [link](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/18-7-conductors-and-electric-fields-in-static-equilibrium/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> How can a conductor have voltage without charge on it? Taking in electrostatics

The following image from [spark.iop.org](https://spark.iop.org/electric-field) shows the electric field associated with a charge.

[image]

The solid blue lines correspond to electric field proper, and the dashed red lines correspond to lines of equal potential. Notice that the lines of equal potential are  also lines of equal distance from the charge.

If there is a very small conductor on one of the lines of equal potential, it will have negligible effect on the shape of the electric field, or upon the lines of equal potential. Therefore, *that conductor* will have the same potential as the equi-potential line on which it sits. That is the answer to the question in your title.

> What does it mean if the potential of a conductor is Kq/r which is at r distance from the charge q?

What this means is that we have defined that any point an infinite distance away from the charge in the diagram will have a potential of 0. We have also assumed that the diameter of the conductor is sufficiently small so that we can neglect any distortions in the shape of the electric field or the lines of equal potential caused by the conductor. As we approach the charge, the potential becomes higher, according to the formula V = Kq/r.

> How can a conductor having no real charge have some potential (which is here KQ/r)?

The conductor can have a potential because because it lies within the electric field created by a charge. It is not necessary for an object to have a net charge in order to have a potential if it lies within an electric field.

(This is a quibble with your formulation. A conductor may have no *net* charge. However, conductors, by their very nature have *charges* within them. A conductor has no *net* charge when the positive and negative charges are equal in magnitude.)